# EMR(Elastic Map Reduce) vs nonEMR(EC2-Hadoop)

Tags: performance, hadoop, emr

What is the difference between running jobs on EMR or on some EC2 instances that they have hadoop installed on them in terms of performance.
I know the key difference is that running jobs with EMR is way easier, but Do you have any idea is there any difference in the performance of these two? 
Let say by performance I mean the time that takes from launching the jobs and finishing them.

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177908/hadoop-on-ec2-vs-elastic-map-reduce?rq=1

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19129440/emr-vs-ec2-hadoop-on-aws